# How to check if something is not in the table

Tags: sql

I'm stuck at one of my homework assignment.

The question was:

> Which l.levcode's are not in b.levcode's?

This is how far I got:

```
SELECT l.levcode, levnaam, levadres, levwoonplaats
from leverancier l, bestelling b
where l.levcode = b.levcode
```

but now I don't have a clue what to do.

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) (You are looking for the 4. join in that link)

Comment: it doesn't show a lot of research effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT l.levcode, 
       levnaam, 
       levadres, 
       levwoonplaats 
FROM   leverancier l 
WHERE  l.levcode NOT IN (SELECT b.levcode 
                         FROM   bestelling b)
```

Comment: thnx for the quick reply!

Answer (score 3):

try this code:

```
    SELECT l.levcode, levnaam, levadres, levwoonplaats
    from leverancier l
    where l.levcode not in 
         (select levcode from bestelling)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT l.levcode, levnaam, levadres, levwoonplaats from leverancier l, bestelling b where   l.levcode NOT IN (select levcode from bestelling );
```